# How do I add bookmark on Android (Firefox or Chrome) so it appears on PC

Tags: sync, firefox-for-android, bookmarks

Both Firefox and Chrome has sync features, but they dont seem to work the way I want. Both Firefox and Chrome is having a top level grouping of the bookmarks, "bookmarks on PC" and "bookmarks on Android". And from Android the PC bookmarks are read-only. I can see them and visit them but not edit them or extend the collection with more bookmarks.

How do I add a bookmark from my Android device (in Firefox or Chrome) to my PC (Firefox or Chrome)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least my version of Chrome (32.0.1700.107) on OS X has a menu called `Mobile Bookmarks` under `Bookmarks`, where I can see my phone's bookmarks. And I can add bookmarks to my desktop Chrome from Android from Menu -> Favorite (the star) -> Folder -> Desktop bookmarks.

Try using Chrome Beta for Android if yours doesn't have that feature.

Comment: That works for me, thanks =) Same solution works on Firefox. The Android-bookmarks are editable from Firefox and Chrome on PC. I'll just use the Android folder on my PC (in stead of the PC folder) and I'll have the same set of bookmarks on all devices.